# How to do a backgroundworker about SAPI SPEAK

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a SAPI speaking background worker in Visual Basic .NET in order to allow my client to continue doing something while listens to the SAPI talk.
I've reached that point, but the problem is if I want to reproduce another speaking, I cannot cancel the current speaking and occurs an exception.

I have the following code:

```
'MODULE IMPORTED IN THE MAIN WORK: argsBackgroundWorker.vb
Public Class argsBackgroundWorker
    Public text_to_speak As String
End Class

Private talk As argsBackgroundWorker = New argsBackgroundWorker()

    Private Sub sapitalk_background_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles sapitalk_background.DoWork
        If (My.Settings.help_voice = True) Then 'PASS TRUE
            Dim reproduceText
            Dim text As argsBackgroundWorker = e.Argument

            'I have put this code to cancel... So? :(
            If sapotalk_background.CancellationPending Then Exit Sub

            reproduceText = CreateObject("Sapi.spvoice")
            reproduceText.speak(talk.text_to_talk)
        Else
            sapitalk_background.CancelAsync()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_saysomething_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_saysomething.Click
        'Support in order to cancel tasks.
        sapitalk_background.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True

        talk.text_to_speak = "SOMETHING SOOOOOO SOO SOOOOOO LONG..."

        'Cancel another text being spoken.
        sapitalk_background.CancelAsync()

        'Then, talk the new text.
        sapitalk_background.RunWorkerAsync(talk)        
    End Sub

Private Sub principal_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Support in order to cancel tasks.
        sapitalk_background.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True

        talk.text_to_speak = "SOMETHING SOOOOOO SOO SOOOOOO LONG..."

        'Cancel another text being spoken.
        sapitalk_background.CancelAsync()

        'Then, talk the new text.
        sapitalk_background.RunWorkerAsync(talk)   
End Sub
```

It works great as background speaking but notice that when I compile the app, it starts speaking a long text. And if I click a button to cancel the current speaking and speak another text, it fails and shows me that it is running a current background worker.

Answer (score 1):

The only idea I have is

```
While Not sapitalk_background.IsBusy
  sapitalk_background.RunWorkerAsync(talk)     
End While
```

If it gets stuck in this loop until the voice stops then I am thinking that you cant stop the voice once its running on a bg thread.